# Alternative to sleep() function in php

Tags: php, sleep, background-task

I am currently using `sleep()` function for achieving some task but I am getting security bug in my sonarqube. Do we have any other function to achieve same task in PHP? Basically, I want to call the same function after every 10 seconds. I can not use a cron job as a cron job requires atleast a minute.
Currently, I am running background task which in I am calling some function after every 10 seconds.

Comment: You can read about ob_start() and ob_flush()

Comment: What exactly is the "security bug in my sonarqube"? What what is the source code you are using?

Answer (score 2):

Try this. After each time the sleep is done, use `flush()` and `ob_flush()` to flush the output buffer. That should solve the issue.